# Springboot upgrade 1.5.8 to 2.0 release getting exception "org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

Gradle dependency related to kubernetes:

```
  "io.fabric8:spring-cloud-kubernetes-core:0.1.6",
  "io.fabric8:spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes:0.1.6",
  "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:1.2.4.RELEASE",
```

Getting the below exception while upgrading springboot 1.5.6 to 2.0.0.Release

Parameter 2 of method configurationUpdateStrategy in 
io.fabric8.spring.cloud.kubernetes.reload.ConfigReloadAutoConfiguration$ConfigReloadAutoConfigurationBeans required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.context.restart.RestartEndpoint' that could not be found.

- Bean method 'restartEndpoint' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.integration.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter'
- Bean method 'restartEndpointWithoutIntegration' in 'RestartEndpointWithoutIntegrationConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnEnabledEndpoint found property management.endpoint.restart.enabled with value false

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you fix it somehow?

Comment: @MiguelRibeiro, Were you able to find solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can do either of following, depending on your requirements:

1. Disable `ConfigReloadAutoConfiguration` if you don't need it:

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication(exclude = ConfigReloadAutoConfiguration.class)
   public class SomeApplication {
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Add the following into your `application.properties`, just as the error message says:

   ```
   management.endpoint.restart.enabled = true
   ```